# File copy action android

Tags: android, file, copy, action, directory

I am trying to make a file copy action with this code
but it gives me an error **Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody   MainActivity**

at the place where i put ****
help me please

`package com.AleXMan.taptaprevenge4songinstaller;`

`import java.io.File;`
`import java.io.FileInputStream;`
`import java.io.FileOutputStream;`
`import java.io.IOException;`
`import java.io.InputStream;`
`import java.io.OutputStream;`

`import android.media.MediaCryptoException;`
`import android.os.Bundle;`
`import android.os.Environment;`
`import android.app.Activity;`
`import android.util.Log;`
`import android.view.Menu;`
`import android.view.View;`
`import android.view.View.OnClickListener;`
`import android.widget.Button;`

`public class MainActivity extends Activity {`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);






                Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {


                        File srcFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/folder");
                        File destFolder = new File("/data/data/folder");

                        try{

                            if(!srcFolder.exists()){

                                    Log.e("Error","Folder does not exist");
                                   //just exit

                                }
                            else
                                {

                                    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(srcFolder);

                                    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destFolder);

                                    // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
                                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                                    int len;
                                    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                                        out.write(buf, 0, len);
                                    }
                                    in.close();
                                    out.close();

                                }

                            }

                        finally{

                                }

                    **}**);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

`}`

I will be very thankful for you if you give me a code which is more better than mine, or give me a help with this error!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line  `**}**);`

with  `}});`

It's a best practice to indent all code. In Eclipse, select all lines (**CTRL+A**) then **CTRL+SHIFT+F** All code will be clear and indented, so it's easy to find out where and what the problem is.